# Linear Layout too big for widget size

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout

I'm trying to make a widget that would be 4x1.
I set the provider as follow

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:minWidth="294dp"
android:minHeight="72dp"
android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
android:initialLayout="@layout/widgetlayout"></appwidget-provider>
```

and the widget layout is as follow

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="320dp" 
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:background="@drawable/widgetframe">
<Button android:id="@+id/butscan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click Me" />
<Button android:id="@+id/butenable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="On/Off"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"/>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="4dip"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:id="@+id/lblcurrent"
    android:text="Test"/></LinearLayout>
```

Now when i try this on the emulator, i get only the middle of the layer shown on the home screen. The background image is the 4x1 portait image from the SDK (320x100).

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your layout width and height for the LinearLayout should probably be fill_parent.

You buttons do not have any resources for graphics but I assume that you are assigning something like drawables or bitmaps in code, otherwise they might not show.  I have never created a button without an image, so I do not know how it would act.

I am suprised that your 'Test' text is not showing, but it could be diplaying outside the size of your widget since your background is bigger thatn the widget itself.  Again, try fill_parent instead of 320dp and 100dp (BTW, I have never used 'dp' only 'sp').

Answer (score 0):

Your TextView is taking over the layout due to `fill_parent`.

You should probably add `layout_weight=1` to it, so it only scales to the available space.